# Touching glasses with first fingers extended

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He poured two glasses and we touched them, first fingers extended. The grappa was very strong.

It's from A Farewell To Arms.

Does it mean that they toasted with their index fingers extended or they expressed one shot drink to each other after the toast? If it's the former what do that gestures mean?

**EDIT**
Grappa is strong alcohol but its glass is long like a champagne glass. I found 2 cinematized ones in Youtube but there was not any scene which describes the sentence in both movies.

Comment: ing clauses always mean at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to hold a shot glass. Considering their size, it’s difficult to fit all four fingers to the glass. While you will probably more frequently see a grip that uses the index, middle and perhaps ring finger, you can occasionally see a grip where the index finger stays away from the glass.
(A variation of the theme is a cigarette pinched between index and middle finger and the remaining fingers holding the glass.)

I am not sure whether the chosen grip is connected to a social group or circle, but it may well be. Your two drinkers in the text share the way that they are holding the glass and clinking it before drinking, - gripping without using the index finger - indicating a common custom.

Answer (score 1):

The context does not give us any clues as to the meaning of **first fingers extended**.

My assumption is that the description merely refers to the manner in which they were holding the glasses. That's to say, with the thumb on one side of the glass and the three lower fingers on the other, so that the first finger (also known as the index finger or forefinger) remained pointed in the air.

If this is the case, it would not refer to a gesture, merely the manner of gripping the glasses.

Such practices extend to other drinks, especially the practice of extending the small finger (also known as the pinky finger) when clasping a tea cup. They don't signify, except possibly the drinker's background (class and culture).

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=fingers+fore+finger
https://www.cliseetiquette.com/raised-pinky-fingers-scone-slicing-tea-faux-pas/
https://books.google.pt/books?id=288OEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=He+poured+two+glasses+and+we+touched+them,+first+fingers+extended.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "convention", but it occurs to me that maybe what they're drinking is ***brandy***, in relatively large "snifter" glasses. Just as the pinky finger becomes kinda "spare" when you're delicately holding a fine porcelain cup by pinching its handle between thumb and first finger, so that first finger becomes "spare" if you're cradling a largish brandy glass in the "palm" of your hand to warm the contents.